# Oracle SQL Instr + NVL on all columns

Tags: sql, oracle

There's a need for a query to search on all table columns using one single row.
This is the query I have so far:

```
select * from my_table 
where
instr( 
Col01 || Col02 || Col03 || Col04 || Col05 || Col06 || Col07 || Col08 || Col09, 'My Searched 
Text') > 0
```

But as per the requirements, the full table must be displayed when the searched value is null.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data and expected output?

Comment: ...why aren't you doing it properly by using `INSTR` on each column separately? Using this approach your query won't be SARGable and will have horrible runtime performance.

Comment: Are you looking for `where instr(Col01 || Col02 || ..., :search) > 0 or :search is null`?

Comment: @Dai: This will be a full table scan anyway, so there shouldn't be much difference in runtime. But it makes a difference semantically whether to concatenate the strings or not. E.g. 'Christmas' won't be found in 'Jesus Christ' and 'master class', but will be found in the concatenated 'Jesus Christmaster class' :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this:

NOTE: Just because this is how you would update your bad solution does not make this a good idea.  You should do a instr on each column and use OR between them.

```
instr(
  coalesce(Col01,'')  || 
  coalesce(Col02,'')  ||
  coalesce(Col03,'')  || 
  coalesce(Col04,'')  || 
  coalesce(Col05,'')  || 
  coalesce(Col06,'')  || 
  coalesce(Col07,'')  ||
  coalesce(Col08,'')  ||
  coalesce(Col09,'') , 'My Searched Text') > 0
```

Another option is to create a "calculated" column that is auto generated on table insert or change that contains the above concatenation.  Then you only need to search one column at query time.

Comment: In Oracle the empty string '' is considered null. `coalesce(Col0x,'')` is pointless hence.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner huh?

Comment: Yep. In Oracle, `coalesce(Col0x,'')` is the same as `coalesce(Col0x,null)`, which is the same as `Col0x` obviously.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner -- I ran some tests -- my code works as expected on 3 different platforms.   I'm not sure of your point given this code works.

Comment: Yes it works. Same as `Col01 || Col02 || Col03 ...`. Because in Oracle, `'A' || null || 'B'`  is `'AB'`. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/2JlV1QqZ

Comment: Thank you all, followed the suggestions and it worked: 
(by column) 
instr(lower(Col01), nvl(lower('searched text'), lower(Col01))) > 0
or
instr(lower(Col02), nvl(lower('searched text'), lower(Col02))) > 0